# How to add multiple views in html page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this two html code  where index.html is the main view as view 1. But I also want to add the temparature.html as View 2. How can I do it from the index.html page? i have added all the files what I am using are added below.

**the index.html waht I want to use as View 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Demo</title>
   <style>
       .hide
       {
           display: none;
       }
   </style>
   <button id="showPage1Btn" data-launch-view="page1">View 1</button>
   <button id="showPage2Btn" data-launch-view="page2">View 2</button>
   <button id="showPage3Btn" data-launch-view="page3">View 3</button> 
</head>
<body>
   <div id="lotOfPages">

   <div class="view" id="page1">
           <h1>View 1</h1>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
   th{ 
       color:#fff;
           }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
   <tr  class="bg-info">
       <th>Row Number</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Time</th>
       <th>Measurement Type</th>
       <th>Value</th>
   </tr>

   <tbody id="myTable">
       
   </tbody>
</table>

<script>
   var myArray = []

  $.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather',
    success:function(response){
       myArray = response
       buildTable(myArray)
       console.log(myArray)
    }
  })

   function buildTable(data){
       var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           var row = `<tr>
                           <td>${i}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
                           <td>${Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].data[Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]]}</td>
                     </tr>`
           table.innerHTML += row


       }
   }

</script>
       </div>
       
   <div class="view hide" id="page2">
           <h1>View 2</h1>
           
           
       </div>

   <div class="view hide" id="page3">
           <h1>View 3</h1>
       </div>

   </div>
   <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Supporting JS for index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

   function showView(viewName) {
       $('.view').hide();
       $('#' + viewName).show();
   }

   $('[data-launch-view]').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var viewName = $(this).attr('data-launch-view');
       showView(viewName);
   });

});
```

**And the temparature.html what I want to see as view 2**.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
   th{ 
       color:#fff;
           }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
   <tr  class="bg-info">
       <th>Row Number</th>
       <th>Date</th>
       <th>Time</th>
       <th>Measurement Type</th>
       <th>Value</th>
   </tr>

   <tbody id="myTable">
       
   </tbody>
</table>

<script>
   var myArray = []

  $.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather/temperature',
    success:function(response){
       myArray = response
       buildTable(myArray)
       console.log(myArray)
    }
  })

   function buildTable(data){
       var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           var row = `<tr>
                           <td>${i}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
                           <td>${Object.keys(data[i])[2]}</td>
                           <td>${data[i].temperature}</td>
                     </tr>`
           table.innerHTML += row


       }
   }

</script>
```

After the advice to request one single file, I added temparature.html file under the  div class="view" id="page2" but no luck. Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <style>
        .hide
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <button id="showPage1Btn" data-launch-view="page1">View 1</button>
    <button id="showPage2Btn" data-launch-view="page2">View 2</button>
    <button id="showPage3Btn" data-launch-view="page3">View 3</button> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lotOfPages">

    <div class="view" id="page1">
            <h1>View 1</h1>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{ 
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>Row Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Measurement Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var myArray = []

   $.ajax({
     method:'GET',
     url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather',
     success:function(response){
        myArray = response
        buildTable(myArray)
        console.log(myArray)
     }
   })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${i}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
                            <td>${Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].data[Object.keys(data[i].data)[0]]}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }

</script>
        </div>
        
    <div class="view" id="page2">
            <h1>View 2</h1>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <style>
                th{ 
                    color:#fff;
                        }
            </style>
            
            
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr  class="bg-info">
                    <th>Row Number</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Measurement Type</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <script>
                var myArray = []
            
               $.ajax({
                 method:'GET',
                 url:'http://webapi19sa-1.course.tamk.cloud/v1/weather/temperature',
                 success:function(response){
                    myArray = response
                    buildTable(myArray)
                    console.log(myArray)
                 }
               })
            
                function buildTable(data){
                    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
            
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        var row = `<tr>
                                        <td>${i}</td>
                                        <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                                        <td>${data[i].date_time.substring(11, 19)}</td>
                                        <td>${Object.keys(data[i])[2]}</td>
                                        <td>${data[i].temperature}</td>
                                  </tr>`
                        table.innerHTML += row
            
            
                    }
                }
            
            </script>
            
        </div>

    <div class="view hide" id="page3">
            <h1>View 3</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `view2.html` to `page2.html` because id and filename should be same to work more efficiently. Add `window.location.href` to `showView(viewName)`

```
function showView(viewName) {
    ...
    window.location.href = viewName+'.html';  //since viewName is page2 so change filename to page2.html
}
```

You don't required `hide` and `show` now onwards. Just move

```
<div class='view' id='page2'>
  <h1>View 2</h1>
</div>
```

to `page2.html`

Comment: I have added view 2 html <div class='view' id='page2'> but no luck. What I am missing?

Comment: @ArafatulHasan Did you changed the file name from `view2.html` to `page2.html`

Comment: I am using one single file now. If you check my last code snippet what I added, its now one single page. Can you help me in this?

Comment: @ArafatulHasan No I didn't see your code exactly at beginning. Since you have two ajax GET request two files required. Keep two files as it is at the beginning and add the code as mentioned above and change `view2.html` to `page2.html`. It works very well..

Answer (score 0):

According to your code place temperature.html table inside below div which has id 'page2' and bring all supportive links to index.html.

```
<div class="view hide" id="page2">
       
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to use it but it does not show anything in the view 2.

Comment: $('.view').hide(); this hides view class so remove class view from id="page2" because this hides view2 also